# Using a CheckBox to Select Rows in an ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, webforms

With a `GridView` control in .NET is there any way to change the `Select` option in a `GridView` to a `Checkbox`, how do you select multiple rows?

I tried adding a `CheckBoxField` into my `GridView` but when I ran it it didn't show up.

Comment: Which GridView? WinForms, WPF? Other?

Comment: I think flavour404 is referred to ASP.NET Web Forms.

Comment: Indeed I do mean a ASP .Net web form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding checkbox to Gridview is as simple as adding TemplateField of any control.

> I tried adding a CheckBoxField into my
>   gridview but when I ran it it didn't
>   show up.

There should be other columns binding data to the grid. Also, check visible property of checkbox.

Refer to this link for more on this. [link text](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/tutorial-52-cs.aspx)

Comment: I think the problem is that the check box is not bound to any data column, I simply want someone to be able to select multiple items in the list but until they actually press 'go' I don't need any postback events etc.  I did originally chekc the visibiltiy property but the default is visible but came to the conclusion above.

Comment: I tried to add a template field, and a check box but it is still not showing up in each row.  I have followed the tutorial, but of course they didn't show the markup so I cannot see what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I always just add a column to the DataTable that I am binding to.

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Include", typeof(Boolean)));
```

Or in my SQL I will have:

```
declare @include bit
set @include = 0
select 
@include Include,
....
```

More can be found on my blog [here](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2009/07/14/Multiple-Row-Selections-in-a-GridView-with-checkboxes.aspx)

Comment: I like this idea and will check out your blog.

Answer (score 1):

I did work it out in the end, thanks to ExpertSoul for the headsup on the tutorial.  This was all I needed in the markup and it worked great:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="PublicationSelector" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The other thing that the tutorial had which was great was an onclick event so that you could pick up the id # when the submit button was clicked, which was the next bit...

Great stuff.